# error when pushing to git-lab when doind git push origin master: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: git

I created a project on git lab and I just did the git remote add origin and it succeeded but the git push origin master is displaying:

> error : source ref spec master does not match any, error: failed to push some refs to 'my git project path'.

Comment: Pasting the actual error you are getting will help others determine how best to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to commit. Try

```sh
git init
git commit -m "Your commit message here..."
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: when i am doing git commit it is giving me : "empty ident name" even that i have configured my email and git push is still giving me error! i have been with this error for two days !!

Comment: @BoutrosDouaihy Please try to enter `git config --local -l` and let me know if it returns the correct details.

Comment: okay it worked for me thank you , if i need something in git can you help me with it? thanks

Comment: @BoutrosDouaihy Sure and no problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: when i did the git init and after it git push ionic master it has created a blank project and not the real projrct that i have , how to solve this issue?

Comment: @BoutrosDouaihy Have you commited the files?

Comment: how to do this step? please help me i just followed steps from ionic view documentation telling me to do git push ionic master i just did it and when i see the app it is blank , i created a git lab account i pushed the code also to it and i just found that the project that is pushed is different from mine it is a blank one,

Comment: @BoutrosDouaihy That's not enough information. You should create a seperate question.